# Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy' in dialog

Tags: jquery

When trying to display a window on my system , the following error , the problem is to update the version of jquery.

But commenting on the line " destroy" the modal window is displayed below the main menu

```
 * USER DATA VIEW MENU log  *
 ********************************************************/
$("#verDatos").click(function() {
    $.post("../controlador/Acceso/controlUsuario.php?opc=2", function(data)
    {
        if (data.error == 0)
        {
            $.post(data.vista, function(datos)
            {
                $("#infoMsj").dialog("destroy");
                $("#infoMsj").dialog({
                    title: data.title,
                    resizable: false,
                    bgiframe: true,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    modal: true,
                    width: 'auto',
                    dialogClass: "hide-close",

                    buttons:
                            {
                                "Aceptar": function() {
                                    $(this).dialog('close');
                                }
                            }
                }).html(datos);
            });
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if a jQuery widget is initialized by checking its data:

jQuery UI 1.9 and up:

```
if ($("#infoMsj").data("ui-dialog")) {
    $("#infoMsj").dialog("destroy");
}
```

Pre 1.9:

```
if ($("#infoMsj").data("dialog")) {
    $("#infoMsj").dialog("destroy");
}
```

The reason you see that error is because `infoMsj` doesn't have the dialog widget initialized on it yet and you are attempting to call a dialog function on it, `destroy`.

Comment: @BrenniBarreiro Great glad to hear that! If you feel this answer was useful I wouldn't mind you accepting it as the answer. Trying to earn rep for privileges =]